# Converting arbitrary json response to list of "things"

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I'm having an unusual problem. It might not be a very realistic scenario, but this is what I have gotten myself into, so please bear with me.

I have an API that returns Json and I'm using Json.NET to process the Json response. The problem is that the API can return a number of things and I have to be able to deserialize the response the following way:

- The API can return a single Json object. In this case I have to deserialize it into an `ExpandoObject` and put it into a `List<dynamic>`.
- The API can return null and undefined and the alike, in which case I have to return an empty list.
- The API can return a single primitive value, like a Json string or a Json float. In this case I have to deserialize it into the appropriate .NET type, put it in a `List<dynamic>` and return that.
- The API can return a Json array. In this case I have to deserialize the array into a `List<dynamic>`:

  - The elements in the array can be Json objects, in which case I have to deserialize them into `ExpandoObject` again, and put them in the list.
  - The elements can also be primitive values. In this case I have to deserialize them into the proper .NET type and put them in the list.

Based on my research, here's what I have come up so far:

```
protected IQueryable<dynamic> TestMethod(string r)
{
  using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(r))
  using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
  {
    if (!reader.Read())
    {
      return new List<ExpandoObject>().AsQueryable();
    }

    switch (reader.TokenType)
    {
      case JsonToken.None:
      case JsonToken.Null:
      case JsonToken.Undefined:
         return new List<ExpandoObject>().AsQueryable();
      case JsonToken.StartArray:
         return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ExpandoObject>>(r).AsQueryable();
      case JsonToken.StartObject:
         return DeserializeAs<ExpandoObject>(r);
      case JsonToken.Integer:
         return DeserializeAs<long>(r);
      case JsonToken.Float:
         return DeserializeAs<double>(r);
      // other Json primitives deserialized here
      case JsonToken.StartConstructor:
      // listing other not processed tokens
      default:
         throw new InvalidOperationException($"Token {reader.TokenType} cannot be the first token in the result");
    }
  }
}

private IQueryable<dynamic> DeserializeAs<T>(string r)
{
   T instance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(r);
   return new List<dynamic>() { instance }.AsQueryable();
}
```

The problem is with the last bullet point. In the switch-case, when the deserializer encounters `StartArray` token, it tries to deserialize the json into a `List<ExpandoObject>`, but if the array contains integers, they cannot be deserialized into `ExpandoObject`.

Can anyone give me a simple solution to support both scenarios: array of Json objects to `List<ExpandoObject>` and array of Json primitives to their respective list?

Comment: and these are coming from the same endpoint?...

Comment: Yes, same endpoint. I know this is not very realistic, but let's assume that this is a given.

Comment: The simple solution is to refactor your endpoints.

Comment: @GuillaumeCR That's not an option. I do no own the endpoint and I have no access to the code either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Json.NET is licensed under the [MIT license](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/LICENSE.md), you could adapt the logic of [`ExpandoObjectConverter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/ExpandoObjectConverter.cs) to fit your needs, and create the following method:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<object> ReadJsonAsDynamicQueryable(string json, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings);
        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(json))
        using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            var root = JsonExtensions.ReadJsonAsDynamicQueryable(reader, serializer);
            return root;
        }
    }

    public static IQueryable<dynamic> ReadJsonAsDynamicQueryable(JsonReader reader, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        dynamic obj;

        if (!TryReadJsonAsDynamic(reader, serializer, out obj) || obj == null)
            return Enumerable.Empty<dynamic>().AsQueryable();

        var list = obj as IList<dynamic> ?? new [] { obj };

        return list.AsQueryable();
    }

    public static bool TryReadJsonAsDynamic(JsonReader reader, JsonSerializer serializer, out dynamic obj)
    {
        // Adapted from:
        // https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/ExpandoObjectConverter.cs
        // License:
        // https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/LICENSE.md

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)
            if (!reader.Read())
            {
                obj = null;
                return false;
            }

        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.StartArray:
                var list = new List<dynamic>();
                ReadList(reader,
                    (r) =>
                    {
                        dynamic item;
                        if (TryReadJsonAsDynamic(reader, serializer, out item))
                            list.Add(item);
                    });
                obj = list;
                return true;

            case JsonToken.StartObject:
                obj = serializer.Deserialize<ExpandoObject>(reader);
                return true;

            default:
                if (reader.TokenType.IsPrimitiveToken())
                {
                    obj = reader.Value;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new JsonSerializationException("Unknown token: " + reader.TokenType);
                }
        }
    }

    static void ReadList(this JsonReader reader, Action<JsonReader> readValue)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.Comment:
                    break;
                default:
                    readValue(reader);
                    break;
                case JsonToken.EndArray:
                    return;
            }
        }
        throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected end when reading List.");
    }

    public static bool IsPrimitiveToken(this JsonToken token)
    {
        switch (token)
        {
            case JsonToken.Integer:
            case JsonToken.Float:
            case JsonToken.String:
            case JsonToken.Boolean:
            case JsonToken.Undefined:
            case JsonToken.Null:
            case JsonToken.Date:
            case JsonToken.Bytes:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
protected IQueryable<dynamic> TestMethod(string r)
{
    return JsonExtensions.ReadJsonAsDynamicQueryable(r);
}
```

Or, you could call `ReadJsonAsDynamicQueryable` from within the [`ReadJson()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_ReadJson.htm) method of a [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) that you create.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DgD4fk).

Comment: Checking out Json.NET: great idea. Also thank you for the implementation.