# Get the results of a CosmosDb query as a Raw string (payload of the http response)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm using the .NET API of CosmosDB and I'm getting a hard time trying to figure out how to get the raw result of a CosmosDB query prior to it getting deserialized into a class. Browsing the documentation, all examples I find cast the results to an specific class or to a dynamic. That is:

```
//This returns a Document, which actually is a dynamic...
client.ReadDocumentAsync(...)

//This returns an object of type MyClass, witch I suppose is cast internally by the API
client.ReadDocumentAsync<MyClass>(...)
```

What I want to do is to get the original raw JSON payload of the result to inspect it without the overhead of deserializing it to anything else.

Does anybody know if it's possible to get the raw result with the .NET api? If so, how?

In other cases, I need to use the result as an ExpandoObject to treat it dynamically, but I find that the "dynamic" results given by the API are not "expandables" so I'm forced to serialize them and then deserialize again in a recursive form into an ExpandoObject. Furthermore, the result is polluted with _rid, Etag, etc. properties that I don't need on my object. It's quite annoying.

I think it's an unnecessary overhead to serialize and then deserialize again, so maybe the optimum way would be to get the raw JSON result and write a method to deserialize directly to Expando.

Or maybe I'm loosing any point and there's an API to get the results as Expandos. Does anybody know it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question that I had earlier:

[Converting arbitrary json response to list of "things"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214424/converting-arbitrary-json-response-to-list-of-things)

Altough I didn't named it, the API in question was actually DocumentDb, so I think you'll be able to use that code.

Answer (score -1):

Seen some bad advice here, but it is built into the SDK natively.

```
Document doc = cosmosClient.ReadDocumentAsync(yourDocLink);
string json = doc.ToString();
```

Comment: No. Your code deserializes the response into a dynamic and then converts it into an string...